# Make multiple counts then sum it in one query

Tags: php, sql, count, phpmyadmin, sum

I'm seeking for solution on how to get count for 3 faculty code then sum all the count in one variable. I didn't found the right query to combine the count and then sum it.

This is the code that I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN `fac_code` LIKE '%JABPN%' THEN 1 END) AS count1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN `fac_code` LIKE '%JABFNT%' THEN 1 END) AS count2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN `fac_code` LIKE '%FPKF%' THEN 1 END) AS count3
FROM `list_faculty` WHERE active = 'Y';
```

And the output that I got:

| count1 | count2 | count3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 69 | 184 | 36 |

The output that I need is the sum of all the count which is 289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding this?

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN fac_code LIKE '%FPKF%' OR fac_code LIKE %JABFNT%' OR fac_code LIKE  '%JABPN%' THEN 1 END)
```

SQL doesn't allow you to use aliases in the same `SELECT`, so the alternative would be a CTE or subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine these three counts in one condition of `case .. when` or you can use `+` between them as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN `fac_code` LIKE '%JABPN%'
                    OR `fac_code` LIKE '%JABFNT%'
                    OR `fac_code` LIKE '%FPKF%' 
                  THEN 1 END) AS count1_3
FROM `list_faculty` WHERE active = 'Y';
```

OR you can use `+` between them as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN `fac_code` LIKE '%JABPN%' THEN 1 END) +
       COUNT(CASE WHEN `fac_code` LIKE '%JABFNT%' THEN 1 END) +
       COUNT(CASE WHEN `fac_code` LIKE '%FPKF%' THEN 1 END) AS count1_3
FROM `list_faculty` WHERE active = 'Y';
```

And the best way in your case is to use condition in `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM `list_faculty` 
 WHERE active = 'Y'
   AND (`fac_code` LIKE '%JABPN%'
        OR `fac_code` LIKE '%JABFNT%'
        OR `fac_code` LIKE '%FPKF%')
```